# How to design API that can have either synchronous or asynchronous response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, synchronous

I need my service layer to support making http requests when the app is online, and also saving the requests for later when the app is offline, however this results in the response being either a promise when the app is online, or something synchronous when the app is offline. I currently have

```
someService.save(data).then(function(response) {
    performSomeAction();
});
```

However the implementation of someService will become

```
if (isOnline()) {
    return http.post()
} else {
    cachePostForLater();
}
```

What is the best thing to return from the service to try and hide the complexity of online / offline saving from the controller layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your synchronous function should return a promise that you manually resolve. That way, the code that is calling the api service can be agnostic to whether or not the call is made while online or not. 
If you include `$q` as a dependency of your service, you can do

```
function save(){
   if (isOnline()) {
    return http.post()
   } else {
    cachePostForLater();
    return $q.resolve(null);
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `$q.when`.

Comment: `$q.resolve()` returns a promise that is immediately resolved, which seems to be what the poster wanted. if you do `save().then(function(){})`, when `save()` is returning `$q.resolve()`,  the `then` function does get triggered. why use `when`?

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a suggestion of how to write tests for this? The 'online' flow is easy with using the mock httpbackend, but something like

            var ranCallback = false;

            annotationService.saveAnnotation(annotation, contentInfo).then(function(){
                ranCallback = true;
            });

            expect(ranCallback).toBeTruthy();

Fails when for the 'offline' flow

Comment: your test would still need to treat it as async. also, it might be helpful to note that, when you resolve $q, you might pass in a value, e.g. `$q.resolve({ offline: true});` in which case you can do `save().then(function(state){ console.log(state.offline); })`

Comment: maybe there are some ideas in https://www.sitepoint.com/promises-in-javascript-unit-tests-the-definitive-guide/

Comment: read [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2735-q-when-is-the-missing-q-resolve-method-in-angularjs.htm) to understand my first comment.

Comment: @vgrafe that post is outdated, "Yeah, they have added an alias for $q.when() called $q.resolve() :)" - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3ef529806fef28b41ca4af86a330f39a95699cf6

Comment: woops! I guess I needed the mental update. Sorry and thanks!